# How to preserve swagger doc abd req.user when using @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)

Tags: nestjs, swagger-ui

I have a method that looks like this, I want to be able to access `req.user` while still preserving the use of `@Body() createOrganizationDto: CreateOrganizationDto` Because swagger will not work without the use of `@Body()` in request arguments.

```
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @ApiBearerAuth('JWT')
  @Post()
  create(@Body() createOrganizationDto: CreateOrganizationDto) {
    return this.organizationService.create(createOrganizationDto);
  }
```

The validate method in JWTStrategy return the user object.

```
  async validate(payload: any) {
    const user = await this.userService.findOne(payload.id);
    if (user) return user; 
    throw new HttpException('Invalid token', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply passing the req object as part of the argument in the controller.

```
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @ApiBearerAuth('JWT')
  @Post()
  create(@Request() req, @Body() createOrganizationDto: CreateOrganizationDto) {
    console.log(req.user, createOrganizationDto);
    return this.organizationService.create(createOrganizationDto);
  }
```